# WSDL Repository

Tags: interface, wsdl, standards

I want my data-driven web app to be connectable to a wide range of consumers. Are there any open standards to implement?

I'm not thinking about low level standards like WSDL, SOAP, XML etc. If I define my own interface with WSDL it will still require custom programming by any client wanting to connect.

What I'm looking for are ready-made WSDL documents which describe some standards which are already implemented by some clients, so they just have to point the client to my hostname and use the exposed functionality.

Currently I'm open to any kind of interoperability - different kinds of watchdogs, calendar-based services, analytical suits, map-based services etc. etc.

**Edit:**

To state a to-the-point question: *Does a repository exist where interoperability standards are stored and mainteined?* (Preferably defined in WSDL).

Comment: What are "interoperability standards"? Which standards are not "interoperability standards"? Why, in general, would it be possible to represent standards in WSDL? Why, in particular, would it be possible to represent "interoperability standards" in WSDL?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I use "interoperability standards" as a more general term for "protocol" or "public API". WSDL describes an interface which a (web) service exposes to the outer world. Standards (standard communication languages) could be described with WSDL (if they are compatible with its basic design). It seems logical to me that other people arrive to the same conclusion and start to develop protocols (interfaces) compatible with WSDL (to encourage/increase interoperability between a wide range of systems).

Comment: Your definition of "interoperability standard" is much more general than the problem that WSDL was designed to solve.

Comment: @JohnSaunders That is true, but I can't see how is it a problem. I'm approaching this from a WSDL point of view which clearly has the potential to be the vessel for such standards.

Comment: Well, I don't think the potential exists. How would you describe the HTTP protocol in WSDL?

Comment: @JohnSaunders HTTP is rather a general purpose protocol, it is content-oblivious (and also is a given with WSDL). - What I'm focusing on on the other hand, are things like e-mail access, querying location-based objects, querying hierarchical objects (something like WebDAV), keyword search, stc. Protocols which have *some* content awareness.

Comment: Good luck. I still feel your requirements are several orders of magnitude more abstract than WSDL can describe. I recommend that you start with WSDL and try to describe a protocol which is _one_ order of magnitude more abstract than SOAP. Simple steps.